# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: string, python-3.x

Eu fiz minha "versão" de um [jogo](https://github.com/calthoff/self_taught/blob/master/python_ex239.py/) que vi em um livro.

```
def hangman(a):
    stages = ["",
             "________        ",
             "|               ",
             "|        |      ",
             "|        0      ",
             "|       /|\     ",
             "|       / \     ",
             "|               "
    ]

    wrong = 0
    board = "__" * len(a)
    letters = list(a)
    win = False
    print("Welcome to the Hangman game")
    while (wrong < (len(stages) - 1)):
        print ("\n")
        msg = "Guess a letter: "
        user_choice = input(msg)
        if user_choice in letters:
            i = letters.index(user_choice)
            board[i] = user_choice
            letters[i] = '$'

        else:
            wrong += 1
        print((" ".join(board)))
        e = wrong + 1
        print("\n"
              .join(stages[0:e]))
        if "__" not in board:
            win = True
            print ("You won")
            print(" ".join(board))
            break

    if not win:
        print("\n"
              .join(tages[0:wrong]))
        print("It was %s, you lose" %(a))


import random
words = ["yellow", "blue", "black", "green", "gray", "white", "gray", "orange"]
a = random.choice(words)
hangman(a)
```

No entanto, no ato de executar o jogo eu recebo ou NÃO o seguinte erro ao digitar alguma letra para jogar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Luiz Fernando/Desktop/PYTHON/magam2.py", line 46, in <module> hangman(a)
File "C:/Users/Luiz Fernando/Desktop/PYTHON/magam2.py", line 22, in hangman
board[i] = user_choice
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Podes colocar o parte relevante sff? Mas eu acho que é por estares a mudar uma string 'on the fly' e em python estas são imutáveis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python

Comment: Mas isso não explicaria porque no código original esse erro não acontece.Perdoe minha inexperiência, estou aprendendo a programar agora!

Comment: Sem problema. Eu experimentei o código original, e realmente não há esse erro, presumo que tenha sido alguma alteração quetenhas feito.

Comment: No mínimo muito estranho.Acho que não resta fazer nada, visto que meu código e o original só divergem em coisas irrelevantes.Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Exeprimentei o teu: https://github.com/psnluiz/crispy-sniffle/blob/master/hangman%20game e também não deu esse erro

Comment: Voce tá declarando `board` la em cima como `board = "__" * len (a) == string` e depois usando `board [i] = user_choice`. Tenta usar `type ()` pra ver se é isso.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está modificando uma String, que é um objeto imutável em python.

Tente mudar a linha:

`board = "__" * len(a)`

para:

`board = ["__" for _ in range(len(a))]`

ou para:

`board = ["__"] * len(a)`

Dessa forma, a linha:

`board[i] = user_choice`

Modifica uma lista, que é um tipo mutável.

Answer (score 0):

A sua variável `board` é uma string de tamanho `len(a)`, [que é um tipo imutável em Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Como sugerido na resposta anterior, você pode alterar essa variável de forma que seja um vetor de strings.